# Python sysdate modification

Tags: date, datetime, python-3.x

I am trying to get current system date in python with datetime of which I have to go

```
   datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%b-%Y")
```

now I would like to try to access the same thing but 10 years from now... so for example

```
   datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%b- (%Y + 10)")
```

So if the current year is 2014, I would like it to give me 2024

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increment dates using [`timedelta`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) objects.

```
>>> years = 10
>>> now = (datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=365.2425 * years))
>>> now.strftime('%d-%b-%Y')
'14-Mar-2024'
```

You could also do (handling the `ValueError` for February 29th):

```
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now() 
>>> now.replace(year=now.year+years)
```

Answer (score 0):

2024, python3.12 datetime module

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.now()

from datetime import datetime
datetime.now()
```

same datetime has difernence, module & type.

```
import datetime
print(type(datetime))       #<class 'module'>
import datetime as dt
print(type(dt))             #<class 'module'>
print(type(datetime))       #<class 'module'>

from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta, timezone
print(type(datetime))       #<class 'type'>
print(type(date))           #<class 'type'>
print(type(timedelta))      #<class 'type'>
print(type(timezone))       #<class 'type'>

print(dt.datetime.now())    #2024-02-22 00:00:23.575098
print(datetime.now())       #2024-02-22 00:00:23.579122
```